# RPAREN appened before NUM?

Tags: python

I am building a mini-coding language and I have run into an error. So I have this function `lex()` that checks what the current `char` is and appends it to tokens. So if `char=1`, then it would append `NUM:1` to tokens. So I have `lex()` check for LPAREN and RPAREN, but the problem is, RPAREN gets appended 1 time too early. for example: is i enter `2*(2*2)`, the `tokens` array would be: `['NUM:2', 'OP:*', 'LPAREN(', 'NUM:2', 'OP:*', 'RPAREN)', 'NUM:2']`. I need this to be fixed.

Code:

```
funCall = False
operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
# Lexer
def lex(line):
    idx = 0
    line = line.replace(" ", "")
    num = ""
    tok = ""
    isNum = False
    funCall = False
    tokens = []
    for char in line:
        if char.isdigit():
            isNum = True
            num+=char
        elif char in operators:
            if isNum:
                tokens.append(f"NUM:{num}")
                num=""
                isNum = False
            tokens.append(f"OP:{char}")
        elif char == "(" or char == ")":
            if not funCall:
                if char=="(":
                    tokens.append(f"LPAREN{char}")
                elif char==")":
                    tokens.append(f"RPAREN{char}")
        

    if isNum:
        tokens.append(f"NUM:{num}")
    return tokens

# Parser

#TODO: Append add all variables to variables.py, then whenever out.py would be reset, add variables.py to it

def parse(tokens):
    equation = ""
    if not tokens:
        return "Syntax error"
    print(tokens)
    for tok in tokens:
        if "NUM" in tok:
            equation+=tok[4:]
        elif "OP" in tok:
            equation+=tok[3:]
        elif "LPAREN" in tok:
            equation+="("
        elif "RPAREN" in tok:
            equation+=")"
        
    # try:
    out = open("out.py","a")
    out.write(equation)
    out.write("\n")
    out.flush()
    os.fsync(out.fileno())
    out.close()
    return eval(equation)
    # except:
    #     return f"Invalid equation {equation}"
while True:
    data = input("KPP>")
    print(parse(lex(data)))
```

Comment: Can you try to provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @MichaelM. what do you mean? This is reproducible because it is all the code you need.

Comment: Yes, but it is not minimal. With the large amount of code you provided, it is hard to track down an error.

Comment: @MichaelM. done. is this better?

Comment: I don't see any `isNum` handling in the `elif char == "(" or char == ")":` branch.

Comment: @user2357112 what do you mean?